# Issue vs Children

Tags: meaning, british-english, semantics

According to Wikipedia, a nobleman and a noblewoman have *issues* while non-nobles have *children*, so what's the difference? I'm not a native speaker of English, but in my poor understanding, I assume that if a couple has a child as their issue, it means the offspring is some kind of document. Also, if Queen Elizabeth and Prince Philip have Prince Charles as their issue, is it correct to say the couple issued Prince Charles?

[Nicholas II of Russia (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_II_of_Russia):

> **Issue**:
> Grand Duchess Olga
> Grand Duchess Tatiana
> Grand Duchess Maria
> Grand Duchess Anastasia
> Tsesarevich Alexei

[Henry VIII (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_VIII):

> **Issue**:
> Henry, Duke of Cornwall
> Mary I, Queen of England
> Henry FitzRoy, Duke of Richmond and Somerset (ill.)
> Elizabeth I, Queen of England
> Edward VI, King of England

Comment: You should include the link to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Note, however, that Wikipedia itself has issues, and that you have misspelled kid, which in that case is KIID.

Comment: Lexico has [Issue](https://www.lexico.com/definition/issue) *Law formal [mass noun]* Children of one's own, "the earl died without male issue". That's a *mass noun* too, so "the couple had issued Prince Charles" isn't correct, and nor is "a nobleman and a noblewoman have issues".

Comment: _Issue_ in this context does _not_ mean the same as 'an issue of a magazine'! It's just a formal way of referring to descendants.

Comment: @KillingTime just printed 2 examples: Nicholas II and Henry VIII, along with his 6 wives.

Comment: And (obviously) if a magazine does a piece about a falling out among royal siblings, just ask for the issue issue issue at any kiosk (be sure to say thank you, thank you, thank you.)

Comment: Also the entire family of children is the _issue_ of the marriage or the person being discussed. If a person has multiple children they are not the _issues_ of that person they are, collectively, the _issue_.

Comment: They're probably using "_issues_" rather than "_children_" to clarify that they're listing more officially recognized children.

Comment: I have seen  this quote somewhere and assumed it was an ironic pun.

Comment: The answers to this question seem to focus on descendants/heirs of blood (as contrasted with heirs adoptive). Would it be correct to say that a monarch who dies with only an heir adoptive has 'died without issue'?

Comment: In modern language your “children” may include people who are not presumed to be your biological descendants.  However, your “issue” are *only* those  who are presumed to be your biological descendants.  (I say “presumed” here because such presumptions are not always factually correct).

Answer (score 13):

Such people occupy a formal position in society. Some or all of their children are their **issue**. *issues* are something else, such as problems or difficulties with finance, personal relationships, emotions, attitudes and other aspects of life.

> [Legal Dictionary](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1032)
>
> issue:
>
> a person's children or other lineal descendants such as grandchildren and great-grandchildren. It does not mean all heirs, but only the direct bloodline. Occasionally, there is a problem in determining whether a writer of a will or deed meant issue to include descendants beyond his or her immediate children. While a child or children are alive, issue refers only to them, but if they are deceased then it will apply to the next living generation unless there is language in the document which shows it specifically does not apply to them.

The Cambridge dictionary, curiously, omits this meaning but it is relevant that it offers

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/issue)
>
> issue:
>
> To produce or provide something official

Likewise, the children of nobility may be seen as something produced to fill official positions presently occupied by their parents. However, although Prince Charles is the issue of his parents, I have never met the idea that they *issued* him; it is not used in that way; it makes him sound like a radio announcement or a banknote, which he clearly is not!

Comment: _All_ a couple's children are their 'issue' in formal genealogical language.

Comment: @jsw29 indeed, but the question asked about noblemen and noblewomen, so my mention of “such people” refers to them. I suggest that the concept of nobility rests on formal positions in society. My prose therefore  refers to the nobility although the dictionary definitions I give make clear the wider use of “issue”, as you helpfully emphasise.

Comment: @KateBunting Even the ones that have been disinherited?

Answer (score 12):

No matter how many children they have, they have "issue" NOT "issues".  And the difference between "issue" and "children" is one of formality, not rank.   A lawyer drawing up a will for a commoner would likely use "issue".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 8):

In British and Australian English as it pertains to the law, [children and issue have distinctly different meanings](https://willshub.com.au/my-issue/).

Issue is a technical legal term meaning [all of a person’s lineal descendants](https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/3-382-5691?__lrTS=20200517210616941&transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&firstPage=true). Children are the direct descendants of their parents. Children are [some but not all](https://willshub.com.au/issue/) of a person or couple's issue.

Issue is used as both [singular and plural](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/issue).

Answer (score 5):

The are three differences between *children* and *issue*, in the sense that is relevant here (obviously, the latter word also has other senses).

**(1)** *Issue* is a broader term: it encompasses **all** the lineal descendants of a person, including the person's children, but also grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc.

**(2)** *Issue* is, grammatically, a mass term. While one can say that somebody has five children, it is not normally said that somebody has five issues (if one insisted on using *issue* to convey that idea, one would have to say that the person's issue consists of five children).

**(3)** As a matter of style, *issue* is used **only** when discussing genealogy and the legal matters that concern succession and inheritance. It is likely to be understood only by those who have greater than average interest in such topics. Attempting to use it in any other context will result in puzzled looks, and quite often will simply not be understood.

In these limited contexts, *issue* is used in both American and British English.

Contrary to what the OP assumes and what one of the other answers implies, the meaning of *issue* has **nothing to do** with the position that those involved have in the society. In the relevant contexts, **anybody's** descendants can be, and are, referred to as the person's issue, regardless of the person's social status (although, obviously, if a person was rich or had a nobility title, more may depend on who that person's issue is, ).

To answer the other part of the OP's question, even in the contexts in which the use of *issue* is appropriate, it would be unusual to use it as a verb, and say that the parents issued their child. If somebody said that, it would be understood (by those who are familiar with *issue* as a noun, in the relevant sense), but perceived as odd. This is similar to the fact that, even though *offspring* is widely used as a noun, it would be odd to say that somebody sprung off his parents.

(This answer incorporates some of the points that have already been made by other contributors to this page, but attempts to consolidate them, and disentangle them from the remarks that may mislead the future visitors to this page.)